# Location manager doesnt stop updating

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

this is my `locationUpdate`delegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    let lastLocation:CLLocation=locations.last!
    let accuracy:CLLocationAccuracy=lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy// the radius of uncertainity location in meters
    print("Received location \(lastLocation) with acccuracy \(accuracy)")
    if (accuracy < 100.0)
    {
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan=MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.14,0.14)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(lastLocation.coordinate, span)
        self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
         print("-------LOCATION UPDATE---------")
        self.getLocationData()

    }
```

I call to this in `viewDidLoad` in this way.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate=self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

My problem is it seems locationmanager doesn't stop updating. My `getLocationData()`method get fire 2 times.

Comment: Have you tried placing getLocationData() somewhere else, such as earlier inside the if statement or before your print statement outside the if?

Comment: Yeas I tried and still same.as I know manager.stopUpdatingLocation() is going to stop updating it. I put it after stopupdating to stop calling multiple times. But not working as expected

Comment: Actually, CLLocationManager would still callback several times after called stopUpdatingLocation() function. The latest location is the most accurate one. If you want function getLocationData() only be called once time, just use a global variable to limit execution times.

Answer (score 2):

```
if locations.count > 0 {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

if (accuracy < 100.0)
{
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan=MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.14,0.14)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(lastLocation.coordinate, span)
    self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    print("-------LOCATION UPDATE---------")
    self.getLocationData()

}
else {
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

this way you ensure self.getLocationData() won't get called unless accuracy is less than 100 and it would get called once

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you tell me what is the locations in locations.count?

Comment: locations not location, it's an array of CLLocation [CLLocation], that's why your code has locations.last!, last means the last CLLocation in that array, so if the delegate method returned one location, you stop the manager from updating, to do that you have to check if locations.count is more than zero

Comment: I did. but still same :(

Comment: do you see this line "-------LOCATION UPDATE---------" print twice?

Comment: yeas It prints twice

Comment: how about this line "print("Received location \(lastLocation) with acccuracy \(accuracy)")" ? does it get printed twice ?

Comment: yeas that also print twice

Comment: i'm not really sure why this happens, are you sure you call self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() only in viewDidLoad? it seems like you call startUpdatingLocation() somewhere else

Comment: I solved it by setting CLLocationManagerDelegate to nil after call to getLocationData() inside if condition

Comment: i'm glad you solved it, although this is not the right way